# Exception in Collection.php line 1543:

Tags: php, laravel

> Property [tipo] does not exist on this collection instance.

Estou fazendo um projeto no Laravel (5.4) onde ele está praticamente pronto, porém, está ocorrendo esse erro, porque eu quero que ao usuário clicar para logar, não apareça a view `\home` e sim entre nesse if/else:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user->tipo == 'Administrador'){
        return View('/inicioadm'); //aqui já tentei com redirect e tbm n foi
    }else{
        return View('/iniciodes'); //aqui já tentei com redirect e tbm n foi
    }
}
```

Rotas:

```
Route::('home', 'Auth\HomeController@index');
Route::post('home', 'Auth\HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Em $user->tipo, tipo é um atributo da tabela de users. Você criou esse atributo?

Comment: O que é este `tipo`? Não seria `$user->role`?